# Find date of man pages without a date

Tags: man

Why do some `man` pages not have a date?

Usually, there is a date at the end of a manual, next to the name of the package. For example, in the last line of `man 1 cat`, the date is displayed as `February 2017`.

However, `pulseaudio 10.0` does not provide a date of creation.

When was the man page published? Is there a way to find that out?

Comment: Arguably, Pulseaudio is a timeless creation... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depend on the source file.

To see the deference, there is how to create a manpage with or without the date using this [example](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Man-Page/q3.html)

Copy the content to `foo` file

To generate a `man foo-with-date` including the date run:

```
groff -man -Tascii foo> foo-with-date
cat foo-with-date
```

To generate a manpage without date modify the following line

```
.TH FOO 1 "MARCH 1995" Linux "User Manuals"
```

to

```
.TH FOO 1  Linux "User Manuals"
```

then generate a new man page:

```
groff -man -Tascii foo> foo-without-date
cat foo-without-date
```

Answer (score 5):

There’s no general rule, even for manual pages with a date: the date might not be updated when changes are made to the page, or it might be updated automatically whenever the program is built, regardless of whether the man page was updated...

For `pulseaudio.1`, you need to look up the source code, then match the various versions with the one you have. The upstream [logs](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/log/man/pulseaudio.1.xml.in) show that the source file isn’t changed very often, and checking against the 10.0 release indicates that the version used there was updated [on April 27, 2016](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/commit/man/pulseaudio.1.xml.in?id=d2a6afcab31f9f8122200ce383fdd5479ca0ebd1).